# How to write higher order functions like map, filter, reduce etc.?

Tags: swift, functional-programming

I am trying to write or implement my own higher order function my way, but not able to write it. 
In below code I tried to write filter.

```
    var array : [String] = ["Sagar","Harshit","Parth","Gunja","Marmik","Sachin","Saurav"]

   //Native filter function of Swift

    array = array.filter { (name) -> Bool in
        return name.prefix(1) == "S"
    }
```

I implement below code, according to method signature of `filter`, but as I know , we can not write closure with return type(If possible then I don't know).

```
func filterArray(_ array : [String], completionHandler : (_ name : String) -> ()) -> (){

    for (_, value) in array.enumerated(){
        completionHandler(value)
    }
}


    self.filterArray(array) { (name) -> () in
        if name.prefix(1) != "S"{
            if let index = array.index(of: name){
                array.remove(at: index)
            }
        }
    }
```

My implementation working fine and filtering array. But I want to abstract logic of remove object from array.

Can we write our own higher order functions or not ?
If yes then please help to implement above one.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And you can define a return type to a closure. You can find a working example below, but for this purpose I suggest using the Swift built in `filter` function which can provide the same solution and much faster.

```
var array : [String] = ["Sagar","Harshit","Parth","Gunja","Marmik","Sachin","Saurav"]

func filterArray(_ array : inout [String], condition: (_ name : String) -> Bool) -> (){

    var filteredArray: [String] = []
    for value in array {
        if condition(value) {
            filteredArray.append(value)
        }
    }
    array = filteredArray
}

filterArray(&array) { (name) -> Bool in
    return !name.hasPrefix("S")
}

print(array)
```

You can define your own higher order functions on collections.
There is a great session about collections where Soroush shows an example of writing your own higher order function extending a collection.

https://academy.realm.io/posts/try-swift-soroush-khanlou-sequence-collection/

```
// Swit built in filter
let numberOfAdmins = users.filter({ $0.isAdmin }).count // => fine 
// Custom "filter"
let numberOfAdmins = users.count({ $0.isAdmin }) // => great

extension Sequence {

    func count(_ shouldCount: (Iterator.Element) -> Bool) -> Int {

        var count = 0
        for element in self {
           if shouldCount(element) {
               count += 1
           }
        }
        return count
    } 
}
```

Comment: I will check this video for more insight

Comment: Why do you enumerate the array and discard the index value? It makes no sense. `for value in array {`

Comment: Also String has a method called hasPrefix. `name.prefix(1) != "S"` you should change it to `!name.hasPrefix("S")`

Comment: You should also change your parameter name filter to condition. Otherwise you won't be able to use collection method filter inside your method. Once you do that you could do it in one line `array = array.filter({ condition($0)} )`

Comment: `func filter(array: inout [String], condition : (_: String) -> Bool) -> () {
    array = array.filter({ condition($0) } )
}`

Comment: `filter(array: &array) { !$0.hasPrefix("S")
}`